# Partial Buffering in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, buffer, qgis-processing

I'm using QGIS and I've been trying to use the fixed buffer on layer of a utility right-of-way(.shp file) in my map. It seems to be leaving parts of the input layer un-buffered. I've made my own shapefile from a line and I'm still unable to buffer that newly created line.

Comment: An illustration of your problem could be helpful to better understand the issue.